# Does TFS interface with MS Project stand-alone instead of Project Server?

Tags: tfs

Does TFS 2013 interface with MS Project stand-alone version instead of Project Server?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by interface? Do you just mean export some data into a Project?

Then the answer is:

Yes, TFS can export Work Items / Work Item Queries into MS Project, make changes in MS project and publish changes back in TFS.